# python3 argparse autocomplete fail

Tags: bash, python-3.x, argparse

i find some strange thing when i use arparse in python3.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

def create_parser():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)
    p.add_argument('-i', help='i parameter', required=True)
    p.add_argument('-m', help='m parameter', required=True)
    return p

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = create_parser()
    n = p.parse_args()
    print(n)
```

when i try launch it with

```
python3 ./script.py -i ./some_folder/some_file -m ./
```

bash autocomplete work with '-i' parameter, but not work with '-m'. If i rename '-m' to '-me' for example, all works good.

In bash i try launch other commands with '-m' parameter, but it not work only with argparse. Where can there be a mistake here?

Comment: Probably something specific to your `bash`, works for me. Are you using something like this https://argcomplete.readthedocs.io/? Or does your bash try to autocomplete the 'module script' `-m` argument of python itself which is not a filename?

Comment: i think about python '-m' argument, but it has -i argument too, and it work )) no? i use it it like in code example.
but i try make it executable with 'chmod +x' and all works ))

Comment: it is exactly interpreted as '-m' parameter for python3, like '-c' parameter. both of this parameters not just a 'flag'. so for autocomplete work with this parameters name need make script executable.

Answer (score 6):

What happens here is that the autocompletion for the `python3` comand kicks in:

```
$ complete | grep python
complete -F _python python2
complete -F _python python3
complete -F _python python
```

The function `_python` that handles it should look like this:

```
$ type _python
_python is a function
_python () 
{ 
    local cur prev words cword;
    _init_completion || return;
    case $prev in 
        -'?' | -h | --help | -V | --version | -c)
            return 0
        ;;
        -m)
            _python_modules "$1";
            return 0
        ;;
        -Q)
            COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "old new warn warnall" -- "$cur" ));
            return 0
        ;;
        -W)
            COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "ignore default all module once error"                 -- "$cur" ));
            return 0
        ;;
        !(?(*/)python*([0-9.])|-?))
            [[ $cword -lt 2 || ${words[cword-2]} != -@(Q|W) ]] && _filedir
        ;;
    esac;
    local i;
    for ((i=0; i < ${#words[@]}-1; i++ ))
    do
        if [[ ${words[i]} == -c ]]; then
            _filedir;
        fi;
    done;
    if [[ "$cur" != -* ]]; then
        _filedir 'py?([co])';
    else
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W '$( _parse_help "$1" -h )' -- "$cur" ));
    fi;
    return 0
}
```

The completion function treats the `-m` flag the same wheather it shows up as argument to python or to the script, so it tries to complete with a list of module names.

One way around this would be to use an alias for the `python3` command that does not trigger the completion, e.g:

```
$ alias py3=python3
```

To make this persistent you can put it in your `~/.bashrc`. Then you can use

```
$ py3 ./script.py -i ./some_folder/some_file -m ./[TAB]
```

which will use filename completion.

Or rename the `-m` flag to something else.

Comment: Yes, I already found this out. Not as detailed as you, but I understood :)