Ansible: ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: module 'argcomplete' has no attribute 'autocomplete'
I had Ansible installed with brew, then I uninstalled an unrelated package which removed a bunch of dependencies and now I get this error:

ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: module 'argcomplete' has no attribute 'autocomplete'

I've tried variations of brew uninstall ansible and pip3 install ansible and uninstall with no luck.
ansible
ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: module 'argcomplete' has no attribute 'autocomplete'
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.6.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/cli/__init__.py", line 659, in cli_executor
    exit_code = cli.run()
                ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.6.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/cli/adhoc.py", line 104, in run
    super(AdHocCLI, self).run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.6.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/cli/__init__.py", line 156, in run
    self.parse()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.6.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/cli/__init__.py", line 462, in parse
    argcomplete.autocomplete(self.parser)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'argcomplete' has no attribute 'autocomplete'

Mostly posting here because I'll find the answer at some point and post the answer here when I do.

related: no answer, https://www.mail-archive.com/ansible-project@googlegroups.com/msg64800.html

related: no answer, https://github.com/hisxo/gitGraber/issues/17

this suggests may be with the completion library, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43110290/292408, I am using fish, but same error happens in bash.

I'm trying to find out the dependencies from https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/ansible.json (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ansible). It looks like the python library argcomplete doesn't exist. I can probably install with pip3, but wondering why brew didn't just install it... I just installed it with pip3, same error.

so, the package must exist, because I see it would fail with an exception if it couldn't import it https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/3af9d0f189d2b053536bea4283afc31cabaefdcf/lib/ansible/cli/init.py#L111-L115, so this version of argcomplete just doesn't have the attribute autocomplete so that the message must be right.

I've added brew install python-argcomplete and it worked for me

Fixed by uninstalling with brew and pip3 and instead followed https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html and pipx install ansible.
I also wiped some other left over ansible* directories in Cellar sub folders and also the python3 subfolders for ansible and argcomplete. That didn't fix it, but just noting that I did do that in case someone else tries this.

See How to set up and use Python virtual environments for Ansible.

pipx install --include-deps ansible
was the correct command
